# Cannot create StorageItem in Outlook Add-In

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm trying to run this code:

```
this.storage =
            Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts)
           .GetStorage("ws_up_storage", Outlook.OlStorageIdentifierType.olIdentifyByMessageClass);
```

It runs perfectly well on some machines, but on others it throws this exception:

[image]

I also tried other folder names, like `olFolderInbox`, `olFolderCalendar`. I've looked at Microsoft docs for this, and it says this error is to be expected if the folder is one of the following:

- The folder is a Microsoft Exchange public folder, an Internet Message Access Protocol (IMAP), MSN Hotmail, or a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation folder.
- The user permission for the folder is read-only.
- The store provider does not support hidden items.

The sad fact is, I do not know how to check which one of these is true and if it's at all possible.

How would I go about determining the cause of the problem and addressing it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle all these cases is to try to get a storage. You will need much efforts to implement all cases. The `PR_MDB_PROVIDER` property allows to identify the store provider, but not all cases such as user permissions for the folder and etc. You can use the try/catch block where you may check the error code - 0x80040102 (MAPI_E_NO_SUPPORT).

However, you may use any low-level property viewers (for example, a free open source tool - MFCMAPI) for exploring Extended MAPI property values. Thus, you may find all the required info about not supported scenarious.

Comment: This sounds like an extreme pain. What would be an easy way to store custom data in outlook?

Comment: You can use the windows registry for keeping any information. Or just create a separate file on the disk for the information you need to store. Why do you need to save the data in Outlook?

Comment: My addin is a gateway to another service, which is accessed via a login token. I don't want the user to re-enter the token between sessions.

Comment: You can encrypt the data using BCL classes and store it anywhere on the disk or in the windows registry (HKCU).

Comment: And in this case I will never run into permissions issues?

Comment: Yep. You can create a file in the user's profile folder which doesn't required admin privileges. Also you may consider adding a key to the windows registry in the HKCU hive which doesn't required admin privileges as well.

Comment: Ok, that might be a good solution to my problem. Maybe you have a link relevant code samples? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error `0x80040102` is `MAPI_E_NO_SUPPORT`, which means the store does not support hidden (associated) items.

Read the `PR_MDB_PROVIDER` property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x34140102`) using `PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`. The returned 16 byte array will be specific for each store kind. E.g. for an Exchange store, it will be `pbExchangeProviderPrimaryUserGuid` (`5494A1C0297F101BA58708002B2A2517`). Take a look at any object in the store in question using [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author - click IMessage, IMAPIFolder, or IMsgStore) to see the `PR_MDB_PROVIDER` property.